# How do you update the state in an array by typing in a textfield using onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The state is not being updated in the array as I type in the textfield, specifically in the array. The values I am using outside of the array are being updated fine. From what I can tell, the values in the array are not being saved in the textfield at all.

I have been trying to manipulate where and how i am passing the array object to the class but nothing has worked.

```
export default class AddWorkoutForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,
        workoutName: '',
        workoutDuration: 0,
        numOfExercises: 0,
        dateOfWorkout: '',
        exerciselist: [
            {
                exerciseName: '',
                numOfSets: 0,
                startingWeight: 0,
                startingReps: 0,
                restDuration: 0,
            }
        ],
    }

    // Proceed to next step
    nextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step + 1
        });
    };

    // Go back to prev step
    prevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step - 1
        });
    };

    // Handle fields change
    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        const { step } = this.state;
        const { workoutName, workoutDuration, numOfExercises, dateOfWorkout, exerciselist } = this.state;
        const { exerciseName, numOfSets, startingWeight, startingReps, restDuration } = exerciselist;
        const values = { workoutName, workoutDuration, numOfExercises, dateOfWorkout, 
            exerciseName, numOfSets, startingWeight, startingReps, restDuration  };
        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <AddWorkout
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );
            case 2:
                return (
                    <AddExercise
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );
            case 3:
                return (
                    <AddWorkoutConfirm
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );
            default:
                return (
                    <AddWorkout 
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );
        }
    }
}
```

```
export default class AddExercise extends Component {

    continue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    };

    render() {
        const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
        const { exerciseName, numOfSets, startingWeight, startingReps, restDuration } = values;
        return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", height: "100%" }}>
                <ClientMenuBar title="Add An Exercise" />
                <h2>Enter Your Exercise Details</h2>
                <form style={styles.textfieldWrapper}>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label="Exercise Name"
                        margin="normal"
                        autoFocus
                        style={styles.textfield}
                        name="exerciseName"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        defaultValue={exerciseName}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label="Number of Sets"
                        margin="normal"
                        type="number"
                        style={styles.textfield}
                        name="numOfSets"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        defaultValue={numOfSets}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label="Starting Weight"
                        margin="normal"
                        type="number"
                        style={styles.textfield}
                        name="startingWeight"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        defaultValue={startingWeight}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label="Starting Number Of Reps"
                        margin="normal"
                        type="number"
                        style={styles.textfield}
                        name="startingReps"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        defaultValue={startingReps}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label="How Long Is Your Rest Period?"
                        margin="normal"
                        type="number"
                        style={styles.textfield}
                        name="restDuration"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        defaultValue={restDuration}
                    />
                    <Button
                        color="inherit"
                        variant="contained"
                        style={styles.button}
                        size="large"
                        onClick={this.back}
                    >
                        back
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        style={styles.button}
                        size="large"
                        onClick={this.continue}
                    >
                        Next
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

There is no error message. When I am going through the form pages, the variables outside of the array are being updated normally, but the object variables in the array aren't changing at all

Comment: it's unclear what exactly you're expecting to happen here--you don't reference the array anywhere, so there's no reason for it to change. If you're attempting to keep an array of exercises, and the text inputs will modify the values contained at a given array index, then you need to (a) track the array index you're currently modifying, and (b) update the appropriate index's properties with the updated values.

Comment: That said: I probably wouldn't do it like that. I'd keep a single exercise being operated on and add it to the list of exercises only after the edits are complete, e.g., I think you're currently mixing "levels of concern" in your components.

Comment: Kasey, what would help is a working demo where the issue could be reproduced. The level of help you expect would be higher when there are working/non-working demos.